# How to create different margins for odd and even pages?

Tags: margins, double-sided

I'm trying to create a document that has different margins on even and odd pages. This is what I've tried:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{resizegather}

\hfuzz=2pt

\oddsidemargin=51pt
\evensidemargin=11pt
```

This would give me precisely the margins I want, but for some reason, \oddsidemargin and \evensidemargin are not independent. When I set one of them, the other is fixed. After reading some answers here, I tried setting changing the first line to

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
```

but this completely messes with my layout and I get a bunch of "underfull \vbox"'s. (Although the left and right margins then behave as expected.) So, my question is as follows:

> How do I make \oddsidemargin and \evensidemargin behave independently without introducing any other (undesired) behaviour?

Comment: Don't adjust internal TeX settings by yourself in LaTeX as long you don't know exactly what you are doing. To change the margin use the `geometry` package which takes care to keep all internal settings in sync.

Comment: `\usepackage[inner=XXpt,textwidth=345pt]{geometry}` together with the `twoside` option uses the same text width as oneside. Adjust XX to be what you want.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, this helps a bit. My vertical spacing (between paragraphs) still changes, though. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Issue also `\raggedbottom`; but this problem usually arises when one has big figures with the `[H]` option. Do you?

Comment: @egreg: `[htb]`, `[hbt]` and `[ht]` actually. Very helpful, btw, if you make these two comments into an answer, I'd be glad to accept it. In fact, after also changing `textheight` by half a `pt`, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LaTeX uses different margins on odd and even pages only if the `twoside` option is activated in the `\documentclass` line.

With the `geometry` package it's fairly easy to adjust the page setup parameters. For example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[
  inner=<XX>pt,
  textwidth=345pt,
]{geometry}
```

would set the usual "oneside" textwidth. Choose the value for `<XX>pt` to suit your needs. Check the [manual of `geometry`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/geometry/geometry.pdf) for other options, in particular for setting the text height.

Spacing between paragraphs can be due to big indivisible objects near the end of a page. If there are many short subsections, this may happen, or if there are big math displays. Curing the appearance is a job to be done when the text is in final form.

A `\raggedbottom` command before `\begin{document}` will avoid this, at the expense of having non even page height.

Answer (score 7):

LaTeX just uses the odd side settings unless you specify the `twoside` option to the class.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
```

Answer (score 7):

Often we use different margins on odd and even pages for double-sided printing. It allows us to knit documents. I use [GOST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOST) layout:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=1cm]{geometry}
```

If you remove `twoside` parameter you get classic layout for one-side printing.

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE!