# Custom counter for oddside and evenside margins

Tags: margins, page-numbering, counters, double-sided

When using the `twoside` in the article class, resetting the page counter creates an issue in regards to the odd and even side margins. Is it possible to declare a custom counter that article considers the page counter for odd/even sides?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{technicalpage}
\setcounter{technicalpage}{1}
\AddEverypageHook{\stepcounter{technicalpage}}
%------ For counting and referring correctly ------%
\makeatletter
\newcounter{labelnumber}
% Same as \label, but also specify counter
\def\setlabel#1#2{\@bsphack%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}%
    {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\csname the#2\endcsname}}}%
    \@esphack}
\def\getpage#1{%
    \bgroup%
  % Define current label (temporarily within group)
    \edef\@currentlabel{\the\csname c@#1\endcsname}%
  % Set a unique label name (unique by counter).
  % Extra {} for intention to use with \expandafter
    \xdef\tst@labelName{{page:labelno:\thelabelnumber}}%
    \stepcounter{labelnumber}%
  % Set the label
    \expandafter\setlabel\tst@labelName{#1}%
  % Do pageref to display page
  \expandafter\pageref\tst@labelName%
    \egroup%
}
\makeatother
%------ End counting / referring ------%
\begin{document}
  \pagenumbering{roman}%
  %On page 1 (even)
  This is page \getpage{page} for intro stuff and the page counter will reset further down. Technically page \getpage{technicalpage}.\par\lipsum
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  Claims to be page \getpage{page}, but is technically page \getpage{technicalpage}\space and should, internally, be treated as such.
  % Should say page 1, as it is, but should be treated like even with regards to margins,
  % because it's technically the second page. So I want't article to consider
  % \c@technicalpage as the counter for determining odd/even page.


   TP=\getpage{technicalpage}
aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\
aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\
aaa\\aaa\\
   TP=\getpage{technicalpage}

\end{document}
```

I found it really odd that I couldn't find any answers on this? Maybe I've searched for the wrong things?

Related: [Odd/even page margins - an odd page has "even page margins"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417209/odd-even-page-margins-an-odd-page-has-even-page-margins), which does not in my opinion provide a sufficient answer at the time of writing.

**Edit/remark**: I am aware of the `\cleardoublepage` and how it should be used before `\pagenumbering`, as `\pagenumbering` intends. However, I'd like to solve this matter in another way than skipping an extra page.

Comment: You could do this but won't the reader find it very strange to have odd numbered pages on the left side of a spread?

Comment: the question isn't that clear but you don't have to use `\pagenumbering`: If you just want to change the number format without resetting to 1 then use `\renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}`  not `\pagenumbering{arabic}`

Comment: As David wrote: in twoside documents, odd page numbers should be on the right. Everything else is **very** irritating for the reader.

Comment: One reason that the question is not clear is that it isn't clear how you intend to use these commands, The example used both `\thepage` and `\thetechnicalpage` in the body text but neither is safe in that context, page references are only guaranteed to give the right number in the page head and foot, in the body you need to use `\pageref` (and define a similar command for technicalpage references.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see your point, and agree with that odd numbers should on the right. However, I still want to know how one would approach doing this, for educational purposes.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In regards to `\thepage` and `\thetechnicalpage`: wouldn't `\thetechnicalpage` work here due to the `everypage` package, assuming no one else redefines `\thetechnicalpage`?

Comment: No, it will work like `\thepage` and give the number  the last time a page was shipped out but that may or may not be the page that text lands on if there is a paragraph broken over a page, or a float is inserted that pushes this on a page.  Try using a paragraph with `\thetechnicalpage` at the start and the same at the end, the two values will always be the same, even if the paragraph breaks over one or more pages,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle better now?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman Not really: I still can not guess the intention here, sorry. I added another paragraph which shows `\getpage{technicalpage}` returning 2 on both page 2 and page 3, which is what I would expect, but  I can not guess what you want.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought you understood what I wanted earlier: Consider the algorithm that sets the margins provided by `\oddsidemargin` and `\evensidemargin`. I assume that this algorithm, that probably exists somewhere in `article.cls`, uses the `page` counter to decide whether a page is even or odd. However, I want said algorithm to base it's odd / even decision on a different counter, so that when the `page` counter is reset, the margins stay correct. Even when this entails having even numbers on the right side.

Comment: It is easier to have the page counter being the internal value  used to decide on odd or even pages and just print a value other than page (eg `\thetechnicalpage` in the page foot) because `\ifodd\c@page` is used _everywhere` (margin setting, positioning of \marginpar, ...) in the format itself and in dozens of packages, and if you change that they will all break, but almost nothing assumes that you print the value of `\thepage` in the document.